# How to prevent console output from cin

Tags: c++, user-input

How does one prevent `cin` from printing to a console screen in C++? Given this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World..." << endl;

    cin.clear();
    cout << "Press ENTER to Continue..." << endl;
    cin.ignore();

    exit(0);
}
```

So if a user jams away at the keyboard, nothing will happen until `ENTER` is pressed. This currently works great, but `cin` dumps the keypresses to the console. How do I prevent this behavior?

---

Edit: I'm working in Visual Studio 2010, and I ask this simple question because I want something not platform specific.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.18

Comment: @Fred Wow really? So there isn't anything standard I could use? Hmmm, anything `de facto` then? TIL...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, you need [`SetConsoleMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686033.aspx).

There is no standard platform independent way, although of course you can write your own `disable_echo()` function and use `#if _WIN32` and `#if __LINUX__` to provide platform-specific implementations of a platform-independent interface.

Comment: I think you could use `getpass()` with an empty prompt for Linux/UNIX. http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/getpass/

Comment: I'm going to try this route. Thanks!

Comment: On Unixen, Ignacio provided a pointer in the right direction.  [Here is sample code](http://cscene.unitycode.org/topics/unix/nossenus-termios.xml.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `termios(3)` functions to toggle the `ECHO` mode.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `termios` is this platform independent? I'm currently working in Visual Studio 2010 right now.

Comment: There is no platform-independent method.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. C++, as a language specification, isn't about your keyboard—that's purely a decision of the platform, and unfortunately the various platforms didn't (even remotely) come close to agreeing on a specification for anything vaguely terminal-related.

Better not to worry about or rely on it.